# Python gdal.Warp gives a None result

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I would like my code to write a tiff file from GRIB while changing the resolution.

So I take file1 (GRIB fmt) and translate it to tiff. The file appears in the folder.

Then, I make a warp, but no file appears. With gdal.driver.Create(..) I can't definitely understand the arguments are required. And I don't understand why Translate doesn't require creating a dataset and warp does.

```
outpath=path+'tifdatasetraw.tif'
outpath2=path+'tifdatasetraw_warp.tif'
dataset = gdal.Open(file1)
proj=dataset.GetProjection()
dataset=gdal.Translate(outpath,dataset)
gdal.Warp(outpath2, dataset, dstSRS=proj,format='GTiff',xRes=15,yRes=15)
dataset=None
```

Could somebody who feels at home with GDAL Python explain the philosophy?

It's my first day with this package, but I don't want to make CALL(cmd) for every difficult function.

Comment: You can find Python examples from the GDAL autotests in GitHub. These should be relevant for you https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdalwarp_lib.py despite that autotests usually write output to memory with MEM driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth to close this question, because the problem still persists, and the code in the question is not clear.

The correct way of reprojecting would be:

```
outpath=path+'tifdatasetraw.tif'
outpath2=path+'tifdatasetraw_warp.tif'
dataset = gdal.Open(file1)
gdal.Warp(outpath2, dataset, dstSRS=dataset.GetProjection(),format='GTiff', xRes=15,yRes=15)
dataset=None
```

But in my new question the other code still doesn't create a file, so the problem is with the whole phylosophy of using GDAL.

Answer (score 2):

Why even do this? You use GDAL_translate in your earlier to just include the parameters to change the resolution.

**[gdal_translate](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)**

`-tr xres yres` :
(starting with GDAL 2.0) set target resolution. The values must be expressed in georeferenced units. Both must be positive values. This is mutually exclusive with -outsize and -a_ullr.

`-r` {nearest (default),bilinear,cubic,cubicspline,lanczos,average,mode}:
(GDAL >= 2.0) Select a resampling algorithm.

Comment: Thank you. Firstly, it's still interesting, why Warp doesn't work. Secondly, what's the python way, you are mentioning the cmd one.
Because 
dataset=gdal.Translate(outpath,dataset,xRes=15,yRes=15) doesn't give anything